# How can I condition that a command stop executing before the bash continue with the next one?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script with a lot of lines using the command gnome-terminal so it can open several terminals an execute programs. The problem is that some of the programs depend of the executing of one in particular that takes some time, so I need to be sure that this line stop running before the bash can continue with the next.

One way to do it is to put a wait time with "sleep", calculating how much time this program needs to run for completed; but someone know a more efficient way?

Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to explain why you're not running these related and dependent programs from inside a shell script. One-step-at-a-time execution is the norm for shell scripts. Read about them. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
xterm -e program1 &
xterm -e program2 &
```

use

```
program1
program2
```

or if you absolutely need them to run in an xterm,

```
xterm -e sh -c 'program1; program2'
```

The more sane solution is to factor out the xterms from the actual script and do

```
xterm -e path/to/yourscript &
```

when you want your script to run in an xterm.

Comment: Sloppy me; I realize now that you used gnome-terminal instead of xterm. Too lazy to go back and change; the beef is the same.